# Disk activity even without data cable

Tags: hard-drive

I had this same problem with three different disks. Some people in internet seem to have had this issue as well but I do not know if there is a known reason for it. Some people suggest that "it's disk firmware running maintenance" which I'll believe if it comes from an authority and not as a guess.

The issue is that an HDD is working (judging by sound) when it is not accessed by any software. Tested this, by running process monitor, disk monitor and simply removing the data cable from the disk. The activity continues. Power off / power on the disks, without the data cable it starts again. It continues for a few hours and then it ceases. Can start again on a different day.

Does anybody know a probable cause for a prolonged disk activity with the data cable disconnected?

I have to add, that I ran chkdsk on these disks and also vendor's diagnostic utility, all came clean, not really surprising, given that 2 of the three disks are almost brand new.

Also, in similar questions, here on super user, people found out that sometimes it's a fan or a speaker, not the HDD. I do not believe that this is the case in my case. I think that the sound comes from the HDD.

Comment: There is an integrated controller (i.e. a processor executing firmware), so it's not a dumb device that would be incapable of doing anything without a connection to a host.  A WAG: since that's an "invalid" way to install a HDD, that could be the manufacturer's method to get the HDD to perform a self-test, e.g. S.M.A.R.T..  *After* the test is complete, *then* the SATA cable is connected to fetch the results.  So a host connection is only needed for a few seconds rather than hours; that makes testing a lot cheaper.

Comment: BTW that's not a "data" cable.  The "data" cable is for ST-506 interface.   That went away when IDE was introduced.  The host interface (IDE, PATA, or SATA) combines data and control.

Comment: @sawdust, there are two cables connected to the HDD. One is for power - this one certainly do not have any data flowing through. In this sense the other one *is* the data cable, that is no other cable has data flowing through in/out of the HDD.

Comment: @sawdust quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) "*All **SATA data cables** meeting the SATA spec are rated for 3.0 Gbit/s and handle modern mechanical drives without any loss of sustained and burst data transfer performance.*" So wikipedia also calls SATA cable a data cable. I think this is good enough for all practical purposes in this question - no need splitting hairs.

Comment: *"I think this is good enough..."* -- I tried to gently instruct you in proper terminology with facts.  But since you want to argue the point (with two rcomments), then I assume that means you're too stubborn to learn the proper technical name.  Whoever wrote that in Wikipedia is wrong.  The interface or signal cable is not called a "data cable" in ATAPI or SATA technical documents e.g. http://www.ece.umd.edu/courses/enee759h.S2003/references/serialata10a.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

*Anecdotally* speaking, most drives do actually spin up if there's power and no data - something some folk have used for warranty voiding actions, like using it [to power a disc grinder](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Grinding-Machine-by-HDDhard-drive/). They may power down to save power, which may explain why it stops after a few hours

Feels a lot like the drives are just working as designed.

Comment: The sound is not of just spinning up - it's the sound of constant disk activity, like seeking.